# case statement to find one value

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to show one row per id but it is returning three.

If the id has a 'y' then it should show a 'y'.

If it shows a 'y' and 'r' it should be 'y'.

If it has 'y', 'r', 'n' it should be 'y'.

If it is just id and 'r' it should be 'r' and id and just 'n' then 'n'.

I can't seem to get it to work using a case statement. Any ideas? Thanks.

I've tried this:

```
,CASE WHEN result = 'Y' THEN 'Y'
      WHEN result = 'Y' AND result = 'R') THEN 'Y'
      WHEN result = 'R' THEN 'R'
      ELSE 'N' END AS CARE_PLAN
```

What it is returning:

```
ID    result
3434   'y'
3434   'r'
3434   'n'
```

Comment: It probably has nothing to do with your case but the rest of your query and your actual data in your table.

Comment: `result = 'Y' AND result = 'R'` is always false, because a single value `result` cannot be equal both to `Y` and `R` at the same time.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: should I make it a list agg so it is  in one row then do case off of y,r,n?

Comment: That will depend on the the sample data and expected result ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Listagg` function,

Writing a subquery and `DISTINCT` then use `Listagg` function.

```
SELECT id, Listagg (result, ', ') 
                  within GROUP (ORDER BY result) as CARE_PLAN  
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT id, 
                        ( CASE 
                            WHEN result = 'Y' THEN 'Y' 
                            WHEN result = 'Y' 
                                 AND result = 'R' THEN 'Y' 
                            WHEN result = 'R' THEN 'R' 
                            ELSE 'N' 
                          END ) AS result 
        FROM   t) T 
GROUP  BY id
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/02cd5/2

**[Results]**:

```
|   ID | CARE_PLAN |
|------|-----------|
| 1234 |   N, R, Y |
```

Answer (score 0):

It shall be proper to use `ASCII` and `CHR` functions for your case instead of using *CASE .. WHEN*, as in the following :

```
SELECT ID, CHR(MAX(ASCII(result))) AS CARE_PLAN
  FROM TAB
 GROUP BY ID
 ORDER BY ID;
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a5a676/10)

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want aggregation with some conditional logic:

```
select id,
       (case when sum(case when result = 'y' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'y'
             when sum(case when result = 'r' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'r'
             when min(result) = max(result) and min(result) = 'n' then 'n'
             else '?'
        end) as new_result
from t
group by id;
```

If there are only those three values, then perhaps this simplified logic works:

```
select id, max(result) as new_result
from t
group by id;
```